# Positive Definite Matrix Norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces, positive-definite

I am attempting to prove that a norm where for any $(k \times 1)$ vector x with $(1 \times k)$ transpose y:

$$
\|x\|=\sqrt{yVx}
$$

for some $(k \times k)$ positive definite (and symmetric) matrix $V$, is in fact a norm. Positive Definiteness and Homogeneity are quite trivial to prove, but I'm struggling with the triangle inequality.

Is it possible to prove the triangle inequality (easily?), or should I just prove this is an inner product instead(which I believe is a simpler task) and use that to say that it is a norm?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that you also need $V$ to be symmetric? Otherwise, you do not even have the _inner product_ you talk about.

Comment: V must also be symmetric, however I believe that is a requirement for it to be positive definite in the first place. (Which I why I didn't mention it)

Comment: Did you mean that $ \| x \| = \sqrt{x^\top V x} $ ? This is the usual definition of the induced norm you describe.

Comment: If you define positive definite by property: $x^TVx > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ (which is usual), then _no_. For example, consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. For any $x=[x_1, x_2]^T \neq 0$ one has $x^TAx = [x_1, x_2] [x_1 + x_2,  -x_1 + x_2]^T = x_1^2 + x_2^2 >0$ and at the same time $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: yes VHarisop, there is a squareroot, I wasnt sure it was relevant.

Comment: @vulcan583: See now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Denote $\| x \|_V = \sqrt{x^\top V x}$ and $\| x \|_2$ for the usual vector norm. We can write

$$
\| x + y \|^2_V = (x+ y)^\top V (x + y) = x^\top V x + y^\top V y + x^\top V y + y^\top V x \\
= \|x\|_V^2 + \|y\|_V^2 + 2 x^\top V y.
$$
Now notice that since $V$ is symmetric positive definite, it admits a square root, i.e. $V = V^{1/2} V^{1/2}$. Using this and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality one may write

$$
x^\top V y = x^\top V^{1/2} V^{1/2} y = (V^{1/2} x)^\top (V^{1/2} y) \leq
\| V^{1/2} x\|_2 \| V^{1/2} y \|_2
$$

However, we know that $ \| z \|_2 = \sqrt{z^\top z}$, so replacing in the above expression we get

$$
2 x^\top V y \leq \sqrt{x^\top V^{1/2} V^{1/2} x} \sqrt{y^\top V^{1/2} V^{1/2} y}
= \sqrt{x^\top V x} \sqrt{y^\top V y} = 2 \| x \|_V \| y \|_V
$$

Finally, this gives us

$$
\| x + y \|_V^2 \leq \|x \|_V^2 + \| y \|_V^2 + 2 \| x \|_V \| y \|_V =
(\| x \|_V + \| y \|_V)^2
$$
so taking away the square gives us $ \| x + y \|_V \leq \| x \|_V + \| y \|_V $, as required.